# Counting m-subsets of $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n,y_1,\cdots,y_n\}$

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to come up with a combinatorial proof for $$\sum \binom n  k \binom{n-k}{ (m-k)/2}2^k =\binom{ 2n} m$$
where the sum is over k such that $m-k$ is even. I would like to count the left side as m-substets of $\{x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_n\}$ but I can't seem to make a connection between this.  I have tried involving logic from the Delannoy number formula without any success. I have tried to determine what a single term for a fixed k of $\binom n k\binom{n-k}{(m-k)/2}2^k$ counts as well but no insight yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose $k$ values in $[1,n]$ for which you pick exactly one of $x$ and $y$, and $(m-k)/2$ of the remaining values in $[1,n]$ for which you pick both $x$ and $y$; then make $k$ binary choices whether to pick $x$ or $y$.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Choose k values in [1,n] for which you pick exactly one of x and y"?  I thought I had an understanding of it but am having a hard time making sense of it through an example.

Comment: @Dan: If you pick $m$ items from $x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_n$, then for each $j\in[1,n]$ you're picking either $0$, $1$ or $2$ of $x_j,y_j$. To make a complete selection, you need to decide a) how many of each type of pair you'll have -- that gives you $\binom nk$ choices to pick the pairs with $1$ and then $\binom{n-k}{(m-k)/2}$ choices to pick the pairs with $2$ (and then the pairs with $0$ are the pairs that are left), and b) for each pair with $1$, whether the $1$ will be $x_j$ or $y_j$ -- that gives you another $2^k$ choices. I hope that's clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Permit me to contribute an algebraic proof of the case when $m$ is even.

Suppose we seek to verify that
$$\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose 2q} {n-2q\choose p-q} 2^{2q} = 
{2n\choose 2p}.$$

Observe that the sum is
$$\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose p-q} {n-p+q\choose n-p-q} 4^q.$$

which is
$$\sum_{q=0}^p {n\choose p-q} {n-p+q\choose n-p-q} 4^q
= 4^p \sum_{q=0}^p {n\choose q} {n-q\choose n+q-2p} 4^{-q}.$$

Introduce the Iverson bracket
$$[[0\le q\le p]]
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{z^q}{z^{p+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}\; dz.$$

This  provides  range  control  so  we  may extend $q$ to $n.$

Introduce furthermore
$${n-q\choose n+q-2p}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(1+w)^{n-q}}{w^{n+q-2p+1}} \; dw.$$

We thus get for the sum
$$\frac{4^p}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(1+w)^{n}}{w^{n-2p+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{p+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}
\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} z^q \frac{1}{w^q (1+w)^q} 4^{-q}
\; dz\; dw
\\ = \frac{4^p}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(1+w)^{n}}{w^{n-2p+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{p+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}
\left(1+z\frac{1}{4w(1+w)}\right)^n
\; dz\; dw
\\ = \frac{4^{p-n}}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{w^{2n-2p+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{p+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}
\left(4w(1+w)+z\right)^n
\; dz\; dw.$$

We evaluate  the inner integral using  the negative of the  residue of
the pole at $z=1$ which yields
$$\frac{4^{p-n}}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{w^{2n-2p+1}} (4w+4w^2+1)^n \; dw
\\ = \frac{4^{p-n}}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{w^{2n-2p+1}} (2w+1)^{2n} \; dw
\\ = 4^{p-n} {2n\choose 2n-2p} 2^{2n-2p} = {2n\choose 2p}.$$

If we want to be rigorous we need to verify that the contribution from
the residue at infinity of the last integral in $z$ is zero when $n\ge
p$. We get for the residue

$$-\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^2}
z^{p+1} \frac{1}{1-1/z} (4w(1+w)+1/z)^n
\\= -\mathrm{Res}_{z=0}
z^{p} \frac{1}{z-1} (4w(1+w)+1/z)^n
\\= -\mathrm{Res}_{z=0}
\frac{1}{z^{n-p}} \frac{1}{z-1} (4zw(1+w)+1)^n.$$

This is clearly zero when $n=p.$ For $n\gt p$ we obtain
$$\sum_{q=0}^{n-p-1} {n\choose q} 4^q w^q (1+w)^q.$$

This polynomial has degree $2n-2p-2$  but the integral in $w$ extracts
the coefficient on $2n-2p$ for a zero contribution.

**Addendum.** We can use the same method to prove the companion identity
$$\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose 2q+1} {n-2q-1\choose p-q} 2^{2q+1} = 
{2n\choose 2p+1}.$$

The sum is
$$\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose p-q} {n-p+q\choose n-p-q-1} 2^{2q+1}$$

which is
$$\sum_{q=0}^p {n\choose p-q} {n-p+q\choose n-p-q-1} 2^{2q+1}
= 2^{2p+1} \sum_{q=0}^p {n\choose q} {n-q\choose n+q-2p-1} 2^{-2q}.$$

Using exactly the same substitution as before we obtain the integral
$$\frac{2^{2p+1-2n}}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{w^{2n-2p}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{p+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}
\left(4w(1+w)+z\right)^n
\; dz\; dw.$$

This time we get from the residue at the pole $z=1$
$$2^{2p+1-2n} {2n\choose 2n-2p-1} 2^{2n-2p-1}
= {2n\choose 2p+1}.$$

For  the residue  at infinity  we  are extracting  the coefficient  on
$w^{2n-2p-1}$ but  the inner  term has degree  $2n-2p-2$, again  for a
contribution of zero.

**Addendum  II.**  We  can  actually  eliminate  the  Iverson  bracket
starting from

$$4^p \sum_{q=0}^p {n\choose q} {n-q\choose n+q-2p} 4^{-q}.$$

and observing that this is
$$4^p \sum_{q=0}^p {n\choose q} {n-q\choose 2p-2q} 4^{-q}.$$

Now introduce
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{2p-2q+1}}
(1+z)^{n-q}
\; dz$$

This is zero when $q\gt p$ so  it provides the range control, which we
have now obtained without the Iverson bracket.

We get for the sum
$$4^p \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{2p+1}}
(1+z)^{n}
\sum_{q\ge 0} {n\choose q} 4^{-q} \frac{z^{2q}}{(1+z)^q}
\; dz
\\ = 4^p \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{2p+1}}
(1+z)^{n}
\left(1+\frac{1}{4}\frac{z^2}{1+z}\right)^n
\; dz
\\ = 4^p \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{2p+1}}
\left(1+z+\frac{1}{4}z^2\right)^n
\; dz$$

Now put $z=2w$ to get
$$4^p \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{2^{2p+1} w^{2p+1}}
\left(1+2w+w^2\right)^n
\; 2 dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{w^{2p+1}}
(1+w)^{2n}
\; dw.$$

This is
$${2n\choose 2p}$$ as claimed.